# How to show progress bar for game in andengine

Tags: android, progress-bar, andengine

I am developing game in andengine..here i need to show progress bar for time up of game.. is it possible to fix progressbar using andengine. i have searched but i got only for android.

Can anyone give me some articles and suggestion please..

Comment: i got solution for this. i juz place progressbar image and reduce the width of the progressbar using progressbar.setWidth(progressbar.getWidth()-1) on time basic so it shows like progressbar is reduced with in certain time.

Answer (score 0):

[AliHafizJi](https://github.com/aliHafizji) has posted some code on github.  Below is a link to that:

https://github.com/aliHafizji/AndEngineHelperClasses

It has a 'Slider' and a 'Level Selector' in this code.

You may find it helpful for your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You may use RenderSurfaceView, where you'll be able to use basic android UI elements as well as specific methods from andEngine.